# Elemento que no carga bien ( :before + content: ??? )

Tags: css, font-awesome

Tomé un diseño de codepen y conseguí amoldarlo para que se viese bien en mi web. Todo funcionaba correctamente, hasta que (hace varios meses) un elemento dentro de un `:before` dejo de cargarse/visualizarse. Es el siguiente: `content: "\f10e";`. He comprobado que sigue existiendo, se trata de un ícono de unas comillas y lo utilizo para dar a entender que estoy citando a clientes que hemos tenido. Quizás el fallo esté en otro lugar, pero he comprobado todo muchas veces y me he re-estudiado varias cosas otra vez... Y nada.

Adjunto foto con lo que me refiero, veréis un "cuadrado" naranja dentro de cada círculo arriba de cada testimonio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se encuentra en esta URL: https://freetouratenas.top/free-tour-atenas-alternativo-exarchia-espanol/

Utilizo el bloque de html personalizado de wordpress y la opción de añadir CSS adicional. No sé si esta es la mejor manera de hacerlo o la más óptima, ya que llevo más de 1000 líneas de CSS, ahí todo junto, no sé.

Este es mi CSS:

```css
  .snip1533 figcaption:before, .snip1532 figcaption:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: #F7B307;
    content: "\f10e";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: normal;
    left: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    width: 70px;
  }
```

He comprobado que el icono que estoy intentando utilizar entra en la categoría de "Font Awesome 5 Brands" y tiene un `font-weight` de 400. Quizás en la versión 5 de fontawesome hayan cambiado muchas cosas y fue en ese momento cuando dejo de funcionar lo que ya tenía...

¿Tengo que incluir algún código en el head? ¿Quizás cargar la fuente de alguna manera? ¿Es necesario incluir en el html algo así como `?`?

Comment: ¿ _Font Awesome_ ?

Comment: Te falta incluir la fuente FontAwesome

Comment: Lo tenía como < font-family: "FontAwesome" > y ahora lo tengo asi < font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands">

Comment: A ver, [estos](https://fortawesome.com/sets/font-awesome-5-brands) son los íconos que están presentes en  "Font Awesome 5 Brands" ¿Puedes explicar dónde se supone que está el "quote-right" en esa fuente? Yo no lo veo. ¿Cómo comprobaste que el ícono "estaba"?

Comment: _He comprobado que el icono que estoy intentando utilizar entra en la categoría de "Font Awesome 5 Brands"_: ¿Dónde lo comprobaste? Continúa investigando: ¡no modifiques el código _a ciegas_!

Comment: El ícono que buscas está en la `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"` y debes ponerle un `font-weight` >= 600;. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :((  Miré mal, lo siento y así es, este icono corresponde a "Font Awesome 5 Free". Luego he probado con font-weight 600 y 900. Entiendo que aquí ("https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements") dice que los iconos solid deben tener ese weight.

Answer (score 0):

**Paso 1**: Agrega el `cdn` a tu html:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**Paso 2**: Cambia el `font-family` a `Font Awesome 5 Free` y el `font-weight` a algo mayor o igual que 600.

Te adjunto un demo:

```css
div::before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   font-weight: 900;
   content: "\f10e";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div></div>
```

---

Me he asegurado de probarlo directamente en tu sitio utilizando las herramientas de desarrollador.

Primero edité el html y agregué el link:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en el inspector, hice los arreglos que te comenté, y se mostraron sin problema las comillas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Jaime!! :) Funciona perfectamente ahora, me faltaba incluir ese código en el head...